# Is there a reason why perror isn't widely seen in code for error handling?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling

Looking at code at stackoverflow or elsewhere, it seems I rarely see perror() being used to report the exact nature of an error. printf is much more common. Is this an indicator that there's something wrong or missing with perror? I'd expect it to be used much more often given that it gives better information.

Comment: Better information than what? In C++ you probably use exceptions, and using perror will simply print the silly "Error: success".

Comment: It'll print the exact error for things like fopen, malloc. Perhaps I should keep the question strictly c.

Comment: Spend much time writing Windows apps?

Comment: Because in many, smaller, embedded systems, the facilities to support `perror` are not included.  Does your code provide information to `perror`?

Comment: There's no guarantee that `stderr` is provided by the environment. Also, consider the case of `malloc` failing: could you guarantee that a call to `perror` would succeed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `perror()` is as likely to succeed as any other printing function - it shouldn't allocate memory. Obviously, if there is no stderr, there isn't really much you can do about informing the user it went wrong. But that sounds like an embedded system with no standard I/O, at which point all bets are off as to handling errors. C as a language is of course still used in embedded, but you probably don't get "printf" and "perror" type functions at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally prefer `strerror()` which does roughly the same thing, but allows you to use the error message together with a printf or similar function that gives further useful [to the coder or user of the program, depending on the type of error].

For example:

```
errno = 0;
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if (!f)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "File %s open failed: error code %d ('%s')\n", 
            argv[1], errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

That way, we also know WHICH file (say it's a program that copies a file, perror wouldn't necessarily tell you if it was the "source" or "destionation").

If the error is for programming errors [or "stuff that aren't expected to go wrong"], you can also do something like this:

```
#define UNEXPECTED(cond) do { if (cond) { do_unexpected(errno, #cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)

void do_unexpected(int err, const char* cond, const char *file, int line)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error %s [errno=%d, errstr=%s] at %s:%d", 
            cond, err, strerror(errno), file, line);
    exit(1);
}

errno = 0;
FILE *config = fopen("config.txt", "r");

UNEXPECTED(!config); 

...
```

That's assuming you don't expect the "config.txt" to be removed, as an example [that's pretty bad programming in general, but perhaps there is a valid reason for it...]

Comment: Don't forget to set `errno` to 0 before calling `fopen`.

Comment: Whilst that's a useful thing to do, I beleive it won't be "unset" if fopen fails, so it's not really required in the cases above. Code that does "if (errno != 0)" definitely should [but that's rather poor coding practice anyways, as errno can be set by so many of the system functions - that you really should use some other method to determine if something went wrong]

Comment: Yes, you're right; it's only if you use the value to **detect** errors that you have to set it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

perror() wont exactly give you the line number where error happened, while your printf() would help you identify the exact line where it is being printed. So I think it as more helpful in debugging, nothing wrong with perror() that I know of ....

Answer (score 1):

If you set `errno` to zero before making a standard library call and that call fails and it's one of the calls that uses `errno` to describe why it failed, then `perror` and `strerror` may provide a useful explanation. Most people don't pay attention to `errno`, much less how to use it correctly. It's an artifact of a simpler time.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using C++, I don't use printf() and co, and invoke sync_with_stdio(false) on startup often. Also, the problem with that function is that it only allows printing the error locally. What I have pretty often though is something like this:

```
// setting errno
if(!foo1(bar))
    throw_errno_exception("foo1");

// returning errorcode
if(int e = foo2(bar))
    throw_exception(e, "foo2");
```

The first thing there is that not every function uses errno. In particular for new code, I wouldn't do so either, but just return `int` with the according error code. So, for those "new" functions, I would have to set errno manually before using `perror()`. However, I don't want that either, because there is usually quite a gap between the failing function and the place where I catch'n'log the exception.

Now, in C, you don't have a way to pass additional info up the stack like in a C++ exception. For that reason, it is more important in C to log the actually failed function and any context at the place where it fails.